Socket.IO reattach handlers on reconnect
In my understanding the whole point of recovering a connection and the whole recovery system would be that you can just "leave the object be".
In the tutorial and my experience it seems though that if a socket gets reconnected (socket.recovered is true on connect event) on the server side it is still an entirely new object. That means all my server side event handlers are gone upon reconnect.
I handle a connection in a connection handler wrapper object that attaches all event handlers upon creation. The fact that it seems the old server side socket is unusable as soon as it gets disconnected means this entire approach is flawed as I need to create a new connection object anyway when the handlers are not re-used upon reconnect.
Is there any way to re-use the event handlers on the server side?
On the client on the other hand, upon reconnect, the socket event handlers get re-used.
Small Example Server Side Code:
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  if (socket.recovered) {
    console.log("recovered connection: ", socket.id);
    const connection = connections.get(socket.id);
    /* Maybe inform the client about the reconnect but else 
       do nothing as the socket is RECOVERED */
  } else {
    console.log("new connection: ", socket.id);
    const connection = new SIOConnection(socket);
    connections.set(socket.id, connection);
  }
});

Though it seems like I just need to do this anyway:
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  if (socket.recovered) {
    console.log("recovered connection: ", socket.id);
    const old = connections.get(socket.id);
    // Do something with the old object like cleaning up sessions it is attached to
  }
  console.log("new connection: ", socket.id);
  const connection = new SIOConnection(socket);
  connections.set(socket.id, connection);
});

